# How to identify a RelativeLayout in the activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to change the background color from a RelativeLayout programmatically.

In the XML file I have done this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/milayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/negro"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" 
    >
```

Then on the activity file, I am trying to declare the layout to change later the background color of the RelativeLayout, as I have seen in other posts here in SO.

```
RelativeLayout MyLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.milayout);
```

But I get there an error: "Create field milayout in type 'layout'"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at your code

RelativeLayout MyLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.<strike>layout</strike>.milayout);

change to this

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.milayout);
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the error lies on findViewById, it says "Create method findViewById(int)'

Comment: post your activity class and let me see from the top to oncreate@novato

Comment: No need Elitz, the correct code is: RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.milayout); Now it works, thank you in any case

Comment: ohkay,Sir, you are even smarter than me lol.. well.. happy codding, Sir @novato